# Getting error while using the H2o AutoML model for h2o stacking

Tags: python, h2o

I tried using the 2 best models from AutoML and used one of them as Meta learner for stacking. Named the new model stack_test. Code that I used is:

```
stack_test = H2OStackedEnsembleEstimator(base_models=[model1_xg, model2_xg],
metalearner_algorithm=model1_xg)

stack_test.train(x=x, y=y, training_frame=h2o_train)
stack_test.model_performance(h2o_test).auc()
```

Error I am getting:

```
NameError: name 'stack_test' is not defined
```

What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 1):

I believe the issue is in the `metalearner_algorithm` specification - it should be one of `"AUTO"`, `"glm"`, `"gbm"`, `"drf"`, `"deeplearning"`, or `"xgboost"`. See the [documentation](https://docs.h2o.ai/h2o/latest-stable/h2o-docs/data-science/algo-params/metalearner_algorithm.html) for more details.

Comment: Thanks. The more specific question here is: Can i use an already existing model from AutoML to create a stack/ metalearner model? If yes, then how?

Comment: @PayalSengupta You can use models from AutoML just as base models but you can't use them as metalearner. Metalearner gets predictions of the base models as its input.

Comment: The `metalearner_algorithm` param is an algorithm, not a trained model.  You train the metalearner as part of the StackedEnsemble training, so that's why you can't pass an already trained model to the `metalearner_algorithm` argument.